# Why is my tkinter widget grey not greyed out?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm new but just wanted to ask about what has happened with my code.

```
scrollDownIconActiveMenus123 = c.create_rectangle(680, 125, 695, 140, fill='#cdcdcd', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollDownIconActiveMenus123InnerTriangle = c.create_polygon(683, 133, 692, 133, 688, 138, fill='black', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollUpIconActiveMenus123 = c.create_rectangle(680, 105, 695, 120, fill='#cdcdcd', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollUpIconActiveMenus123InnerTriangle = c.create_polygon(683, 113, 692, 113, 688, 108, fill='black', state=tk.HIDDEN)

scrollDownIconActiveMenus4 = c.create_rectangle(695, 385, 680, 370, fill='#cdcdcd', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollDownIconActiveMenus4InnerTriangle = c.create_polygon(683, 373, 692, 373, 688, 378, fill='black', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollUpIconActiveMenus4 = c.create_rectangle(695, 365, 680, 350, fill='#cdcdcd', state=tk.HIDDEN)
scrollUpIconActiveMenus4InnerTriangle = c.create_polygon(683, 363, 692, 363, 688, 358, fill='black', state=tk.HIDDEN)

hiringScrollPages = 0
buildingScrollPages = 0
hiringScrollPages = 0
decorationScrollPages = 0
mallManagementScrollPages = 0

          def showShopManagementMenu(event):
                    '''Shows/Hides What is applicable to the adjacent key pressed'''
                    c.itemconfig(taskbarBuildingMenu, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(taskbarHiringMenu, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(taskbarDecorationMenu, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(taskbarMallManagementMenu, state=tk.NORMAL)
                    
                    c.itemconfig(securityGuardHiringButton, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(vendorHiringButton, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(janitorHiringButton, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    
                    c.itemconfig(buildingMenuText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(hiringMenuText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(decorationMenuText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(mallManagementMenuText, state=tk.NORMAL)

                    c.itemconfig(janitorPlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(securityGuardPlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(vendorPlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)

                    c.itemconfig(emptyRentableStore, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle1, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle2, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle3, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(bench, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(floor, state=tk.HIDDEN)

                    c.itemconfig(emptyStorePlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle1PlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle2PlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(storeStyle3PlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(benchPlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                    c.itemconfig(floorPlacementText, state=tk.HIDDEN)

                    if mallManagementScrollPages >= 1:
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconActiveMenus123, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconActiveMenus123InnerTriangle, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconActiveMenus123, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconActiveMenus123InnerTriangle, state=tk.HIDDEN)

                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconActiveMenus4, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconActiveMenus4InnerTriangle, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconActiveMenus4, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconActiveMenus4InnerTriangle, state=tk.NORMAL)
                    else:
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconGreyedMenus123, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconGreyedMenus123InnerTriangle, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconGreyedMenus123, state=tk.HIDDEN)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconGreyedMenus123InnerTriangle, state=tk.HIDDEN)

                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconGreyedMenus4, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollDownIconGreyedMenus4InnerTriangle, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconGreyedMenus4, state=tk.NORMAL)
                        c.itemconfig(scrollUpIconGreyedMenus4InnerTriangle, state=tk.NORMAL)


c.bind_all('<KeyPress-4>', BasicGUIFeatures.showShopManagementMenu)
```

My problem is with the showShopManagement() function. Could someone help me how to fix it so that it is #cdcdcd not #a2a2a2.

I ran the code and I was expecting the colour to be darker but instead it is light grey. If someone knows what is wrong with this code, please let me know.

Comment: It's very difficult to analyze a program which lacks important parts for it to function.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)